# Have old web site immediately redirect to new web site?

Tags: html

I need to redirect my old site to my new one so that it is a seamless transition for those who still visit the old one.

Thanks

Comment: What server are you running? IIS? Apache? And what language are you usign (PHP, Ruby, ASP.NET?) Server-side redirection will probably be the best option you have.

Comment: @Michael: with an HTTP redirect, the old site won’t appear. Its address will stay in the address bar until the redirect comes back, but the user won’t get sent the old site.

Comment: @Paul Ah, I was thinking of "refresh", not "redirect".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally I'd show a "this site has moved to ..." message for a few seconds before redirecting, so people know to stop bookmarking the old site in case you want to drop it.

The actual redirect comes in three flavors:

1. the redirect header: `header('Location: http://newaddres')` in php or `Response.Redirect` in asp.net. This is instantaneous because it's server side, the user won't see a temporary page and wait for it to load, but it won't let you display the message.
2. html meta refresh: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://newaddress">`. Doesn't require javascript, can setup a delay to show your message, but isn't instantaneous. The client has to make a second request to the new site.
3. javascript redirect: `location.href='http://newaddress'`. Obviously requires javascript or it won't work. Can still setup a delay with `setTimeout`. Overall the weakest method because web crawlers (like google) won't follow the link, nor will people with javascript disabled be able to see your site.

My vote is for #2 with a temporary message explaining the redirect. It's a great balance between not bugging the user much and eventually being able to safely drop the old site.

Comment: #2 doesn’t tell non-humans (e.g. Google) that the site has changed address though. HTTP code 301 “Moved permanently” does that.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, I’m talking nonsense again: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/searchblog/archive/2010/11/30/search-engines-treat-meta-refresh-the-same-as-301-redirects.aspx

Comment: @Paul, that's beyond my field of expertise, but I really like sites telling *me* that they changed rather than telling Google that :)

Comment: Additionally, if you are using an .htaccess file, you could place the redirect logic there: `redirect 301 /index.html http://www.example.org/index.html`

Comment: @Blindy: sure, but they can do that on the new address. And the OP did ask for it to be seamless for users who still visit the old address, so I’m assuming he doesn’t actually want users to think about it.

Comment: @Paul, maybe he just didn't think about it, figured I'd point out the possibility and possible benefits.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.location.href = 'http://yournewwebsite.com';
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: This will not work if the user has JS disabled and it isn't seamless like @Milo requested (its rather choppy compared to server-side solutions). Additionally, it can be bad for SEO (not quite sure...)

Comment: About the js disabled - fair enough.  With regards to everything else, got any 'constructive' criticism?

Comment: `document.location` isn't the cross-browser-friendly way to do this. You should use `location.href`.

Comment: Sorry if I came off as rude or abrupt, I was just trying to point out the shortcomings in your solution. I would have gone into detail about alternate solutions had I known more about the makeup of Milo's site (ASP, PHP, Ruby, etc.)